# Can I insert blade syntax using Jquery and variables

Tags: jquery, laravel

I would like to put data I got from $.getJSON method into a dropdown with option.
The data are ID's from cities, in my Place model, but I need the names of them, which I should get by foreign key relations.
This is what I have so far:
Controller:

```
public function qryCities ($id){
        $places_city_id = Place::where('country_id', '=', $id)
            ->get();


        return response()->json($places_city_id);
    }
```

Index:

```
$.getJSON('/applications/qryCities/' + id)
                        .done(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            let str;
                            for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                                let $foundCity = data[j]['city_id'];
                                let $id = '\{\{'+ $foundCity + '->city->id\}\}';
                                let $city = '\{\{'+$foundCity + '->city->city\}\}';
                                str += "<option value='" + $id + "'>" + $city + "</option>";
                            }
                            $("#city" + i).empty();
                            $("#city" + i).append(str);
                        });
```

This is what should be put in blade syntax:

```
<option value="{{$city->city->id}}">{{ $city->city->city }}</option>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Blade is essentially a wrapper around php executed on the server. jQuery is going to be executed on the client.

Comment: So what I want is not possible? Do you know another way, 'cause I can get the Places I need, but in places I have city_id, which refers to table City, which I need the name from. I tried with my sql query already but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it, sorry. This is what I did in my controller:

```
public function qryCities ($id){
        $places_city_id = City::whereHas('places', function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('country_id', 'like', $id);
        })->get();

        return response()->json($places_city_id);
    }
```